# Why does math.bignumber() return an object? And how can I use it?

Tags: javascript, math.js

I am really confused using math.js's bignumber function. When I use their examples in both the console, and within script tags, math.bignumber() returns a Decimal object. How do I use this object to get an actual float to use?

Example code:

```
math.add(math.bignumber(0.1), math.bignumber(0.3))
```

Returns:

```
Decimal {s: 1, e: -1, d: [5000000]}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something wrong in the math.js file I downloaded?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a big number library to do math that can't be represented in a native number type?

Comment: Oh I guess i do not understand the purpose of a bignumber library then (Kinda new to this stuff). I am trying to model Simpsons Rule and I want it to be more accurate than just 16 decimal places (like I'm trying to get to 64). You can see my code at ethanarrowood.com/simsponsrule/script.js

Comment: Perhaps you want to output a string then?

Answer (score 3):

The examples don't use console.log but `print` which is defined as follows

```
function print (value) {
  console.log(math.format(value));
}
```

If you use print, it should work

Comment: please check it as correct answer, its work for me

Answer (score 0):

const result = math.add(math.bignumber(0.1), math.bignumber(0.3))
console.log(math.format(result)) // it will give you 0.4